# How can I persist List<String> into single column using GORM and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I want to persist a List<String> field into a single VARCHAR column using Grails with GORM and Hibernate. I have written a Hibernate custom type but cannot figure out how to get GORM/Hibernate to treat the list field as persistent:

```
class User {
    List<String> listOfStrings
    static mapping = {
        listOfStrings(type: StringListType, length: 512)
    }
}
```

The 'listOfStrings' mapping is ignored. Any ideas? For now I have worked around the problem using an extra String field and a set/get to encode and decode the List.

Comment: can't you use the `@Type(..)` annotation?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't written custom types before, but one thought I'd have for you is to make listOfStrings a transient variable, and have an event handler to marshall and unmarshall the list of strings for you.    E.g. onLoad could do a `listOfStrings = internalVarName.split()`, and onUpdate could do `internalVarName = listOfStrings.join(' ')`.

Another idea would be to wrap List of Strings into your own type, as GORM may have special handling for associations that includes specific code for types.  I don't know that for a fact, just speculating.

Comment: The first part of your answer is essentially what I have done. I really don't want to have to create a ListOfStrings type to make this work if I don't have to. Would prefer to go with current workaround.

Comment: I think the second option has more merit. In the first option, what happens when one of your strings has the delimiter character(s) in it?

Comment: @Matt - Agreed that the second solution is more architecturally pure - but it depends if you want to go through the headache of creating a new class, etc.   The first solution will get the job done, and as far as the delimiters - that obviously depends on the type of data you expect.  If it's a multi-select dropdown, for example, then you can manage the delimiters easily.